# Checking the type of POST data received in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In my sinatra app i have a form which is used to submit data via a POST request to a url.The url also accepts json sent in a POST request.
Is there any way to determine in the handler if json data was received in the post or the data submitted was sent from the form ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send data via a Post request you will have data in your `params` Hash. So if there is a key there is a value, even if it's empty. So you can check for example via `params[:json]` if you have received something via json (assuming you call that parameter :json). The same goes for data. But then I'm not entirely sure if that's what you're asking for. Either way all data you get is handled via the `params` variable.

Comment: A small addition to this answer is, when the form data is submitted, the `params` hash is a Ruby Hash. This hash will have the submit button's name as the key. This probably would help, for example, if you check whether the params hash contains that key.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that JSON is sent via XHR call, you can make use of request.xhr? to check if the request is xhr.